# How do I use angular.js with jsdt-jquery?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, angularjs, jsdt

In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989859/what-is-the-best-ide-for-angularjs
[Tonte Pouncil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743588/tonte-pouncil) mentioned that it's possible to add angular.js as a library in jsdt-jquery. How does one go about doing this? thanks!

Comment: Are you tied to eclipse? The plugin for IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm is really good. It even auto-completes ng- style tags in HTML.

Comment: Does it work with the free version of IntelliJ IDEA? I've invested a lot of time in my Eclipse setup, but I'm open to trying out other IDEs, as long as they're free and plays nice with PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install  https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse, you will benefit from

- AngularjS features, in other words completion, hyperlink in [HTML editor](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/HTML-Features) and [Javascript editor](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Javascript-Features).
- [jQuery completion](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-jQuery-support) because AngularJS Eclipse is based on the Javascript Inference engine [tern.js](http://ternjs.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is possible to add libraries to JSDT as well. I am not aware of such libraries. But there is angularjs-eclipse Eclipse plugin, see  https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse

[image]

[image]